# can provide me example of xsrf token in angular js( front end ) and laravel ( backend side )

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

i am using **angular js** for front end and **laravel** for back end.

can anyone provide me the complete example of how to setup **xsrf token**

so i dont get error of cross origin.

i have angular js **module** as follow

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
```

and my **service** is as follow

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('communitiesService', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/communities/searchcommunities');
        }
    }
});
```

can anyone provide me the complete example and explain.

thnak you

Comment: Please explain the approaches you have tried. We cannot give you the complete solutions. If you try something and want some suggestions then this is the right place

Comment: i don't know the approach thats why i had asked the  question.@ShaikMahaboobBasha

Comment: i had seen angular documentation but i didn't find any solution or way.

Comment: Are you talking about passing the token in the headers to the server?